# How to create a custom keyboard shortcut for this nested menu item? [Mac]

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to create a shortcut; it is described on Apple website [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?locale=en_US). However, I came across a tricky case: I want to create a shortcut for the TextEdit application, particularly for setting the writing direction to `Right to Left`. The hierarchy for this is shown below:

[image]

I think that the problem is with the `Paragraph` word written in grey.

I've tried

```
Format->Text->Writing Direction->Right to Left
```

and

```
Format->Text->Writing Direction->Paragraph->Right to Left
```

and others, but none have worked.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know how to set up shortcut but you could set the default to right-to-left and maybe reduce number of times you have to covert unless Textedit is used a lot for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a style that writes from right-to-left and then whenever you open a textedit file choose that particular style. The style option appears in header bar so its easy to set. Not as convenient as your shortcut but easy to setup and use.